# Exist one way to use JQuery with Selenium IDE 2.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, testing, primefaces

For make test fast, used Selenium IDE 2.9.1, in browser Firefox, make a record views, then Selenium record actions executed, but is same case the function not enough, for write HTML.

- When need use javascript commands, but Selenium cant find one tag DOM and set value.
- For example!
  [Text Editor Primefaces - set value](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/textEditor.xhtml)
- **Exist a way to use JQuery with libray js**?. for Selenium IDE 2.9.1 in forefox

Se image windows pluging

[image]

Exist other plugins with this proposit, can use JQuery?

Comment: how is this actually PrimeFaces related?

Comment: Ya, if you install Selenium IDE and try test, you see, Plugin can't record to write text in box Text.